# How to get PHP script to ignore max_execution_time and run forever

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that loops forever, checking values and logging them.

How can I get the PHP script to ignore max_execution_time? Do I just set max_execution_time to a huge value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the value to 0 will turn off the limitation.

When working with PHP, the online manual should/must be your best friend:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php